# Problems with Wordpress in subfolder, posts show a blank page

Tags: posts, permalinks

I have wordpress installed in a subfolder and using permalinks but I'm getting a blank page when I try to access to any post.

This is what I have in the root folder .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/index.php [L]
```

And this is what wordpress put in the subfolder .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm using custom permalinks with `/%postname%.html`, the posts have the permalink correctly but when I try to access it shows only an empty blank page.

Comment: what happens when you remove root .htaccess and just use the one in the subfolder? (as a test - i understand the root one is needed too) - I think the two are conflicting.

Comment: If I remove the .htaccess in root the domain just dont look for index in the root folder.

Comment: did it worked BEFORE the permalik change ? did you configured the wp URL/folder and blog URL/folder in options ?

Comment: The permalink was always working, the problem its the code in the root .htaccess to redirect to the subfolder.

Comment: Do you want to show up your blog on main domain keeping all files in subdirectory ?

Answer (score 1):

try using a blank htaccess file in your root folder and from there you can do a 301 redirect to your WP folder. i have had the same kind of issues with some hosts and always solved that way, it's not WP, it's always a faulty htaccess

Comment: ¿How I do 301 redirect?

Comment: you can do it via your control panel or you can simply take a look at http://www.tamingthebeast.net/articles3/spiders-301-redirect.htm (since it depends on your site and there are several options)

Comment: I'm using cPanel and it say that I can't make a 301 redirect of the main domain.